# Кибер Иисус, кибериисус или кибер-иисус?

Tags: слитно-раздельно, слитно-дефис

Как правильно пишется приставка кибер- с именами собственными, например кибериисус, кибер-иисус или кибер Иисус, должна ли быть первая буква быть заглавной Кибер

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 4):

Правильно: **кибер-Иисус**.

Вообще-то, сложные слова с первой частью *кибер-* пишутся слитно (см. [ответ справочной службы русского языка](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=290247)). Но тут мы имеем дело с именем, которое пишется с прописной буквы.

Подобный вопрос задавался на сайте Грамота.ру по поводу слова *супер-Лиза* (а сложные слова с первой частью *супер-* тоже пишутся слитно):

> [Вопрос № 286860](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=286860)
>   Как написать такое сочетание "СуперЛиза"? Речь идет о девушке Лизе, которую автор возвел в ранг "супер".
>   **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>   Орфографически правильно: супер-Лиза. Недопустимы слитные написания с прописной буквой в середине слова.